# Additional Storage Besides your Bag

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I know that you can upgrade your bag size, but is there a place to store items other than your bag, like a chest or a bank? If so, is their a map icon to locate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are banks throughout Tamriel, mostly located in large cities. Banks will store both items and gold, and their storage space is upgradeable. But, their space is also shared among all characters across your account; this is useful for transferring items, but also means that if you fill your bank on one character, you won't have that space on any others.

The other way you can gain more storage, is by buying a horse. Most horses by default won't provide you any benefit, but once per day you can feed your horse at a stable, which will increase either their speed, stamina, or carrying capacity, depending on what you feed it. Your horse's carrying capacity bonus is then simply added to the number of items you can carry on that character.

Banks will typically appear on your map with the following icon:

[image: Bank Icon]

And Stables will appear with this one:

[image: Stable Icon]

Note that in some cities, there will be several different services offered in a single small building, or the same section of a larger building, all represented with one icon. When this happens, a bank or stable might be present, without their specific icon. Just mouse over the other icons in that part of the map, and it will list all the people at that location, with separate smaller icons for each.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but since all of your characters share the bank account, I created a second, completely different character for the sole purpose of storage(my main character is a Bosmer Nightblade in the Aldmeri Dominion and my second is a Breton Templar in the Daggerfall Covenant). I only "cook" when I do the writs so I deposit all of my provision materials in the bank and then have my second character withdraw them to free up the space. When I get a provisioning writ I research what ingredients I need and then make the switch. It's time consuming, what with the loading and all, but it's definitely worth it. I also deposit items like crafting motifs and recipes that I've already learned so that my second character can withdraw and learn from them and be prepared when I start their quest line.